# I want to readers/writers problem with binary semaphore

Tags: c, multithreading, binary-semaphore

I have 5 writers, 20 readers.
I want to solve readers/writers problem with binary semaphore.

But my code has some problem. There is segmentation fault(core dumped).
I think that there is a problem when creating threads. 
How can I solve the problem? and Is this right code to solve r/w problem? 
I used my text book's pseudo code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t mutex, rw_mutex;

int data = 0;
int readcount = 0;

void *reader(void* i)
{
    int num = *((int*)i);
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    readcount += 1; 
    if(readcount == 1)
            sem_wait(&rw_mutex);
    sem_post(&mutex);

    printf("I'm reader%d, data is %d \n", num, data);
    sem_wait(&mutex);

    readcount -= 1;
    if( readcount == 0)
            sem_post(&rw_mutex);
    sem_post(&mutex);
}

void *writer(void *i)
{
      int num = *((int*)i);
      sem_wait(&rw_mutex);
      data++;
      printf("I'm writer%d, data is %d\n", num, data);
      sem_post(&rw_mutex);
}

void main()
{
      int i;
      pthread_t writer[5], reader[20];
      sem_init(&rw_mutex, 0, 1);
      sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

      for(i=0; i<5; i++)
              pthread_create(&writer[i], NULL, writer, &i);
      for(i=0; i<20; i++)
              pthread_create(&reader[i], NULL, reader, &i);
      for(i=0; i<5; i++)
            pthread_join(writer[i], NULL);
      for(i=0; i<20; i++)
              pthread_join(reader[i], NULL);
      printf("End \n");
}
```

Comment: A segmentation fault almost always indicates that you are misusing memory, typically by trying to read from or write to an address outside those available to your program.  Running your code under a tool such as Valgrind will help you detect where such errors are occurring.

Comment: @Yogesh locks and semaphores have different semantics. They are not a replacement for each other.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the warnings from your compiler? I get several warnings. One example is:

> warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>                  pthread_create(&reader[i], NULL, reader, &i);

The problem is that in `main` you have an array with the name `reader` but in the program you also have a function named `reader`. So the compiler (i.e. at least my compiler) use the array when you actually want the function. And the program crash.

Fix the warnings! Either by renaming the functions `reader` and `writer` or by renaming the arrays.

After that I don't see a program crash anymore.

Comment: I couldn't understand that warning. Thanks for giving me the meaninig of the warning. But there is another problem. The result I expected was reader[2] reader[3] read something, and writer[2] writer[3] write something. But the result is 
I'm reader0, data is 0 I'm writer0, data is 1 I'm writer0, data is 2 I'm writer0, data is 3
I'm writer0, data is 4
I'm writer0, data is 5

Comment: How can i fix this problem?

Comment: @su00 I think that you you should ask a new question for the new problem. This question was about a core dump. Now that the core dump is solved, you have a new problem that requires a new question. Anyway - passing `&i` is a bad idea but I'm not sure that is the problem