# I have problem using thread passing argument

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to solve readers/writers problem using binary semaphore.

The result I expected was I'm writer2 , data is 1. I'm reader3, data is 2.

But, result is I'm writer0 , and I'm reader0 data1 , data2 ~ data5.
How can I fix my code?

```
int data = 0; // global variable.
void main()
{
    //other code is omitted.

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
            pthread_create(&w[i], NULL, writer, &i);

    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
            pthread_create(&r[i], NULL, reader, &i);

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
            pthread_join(w[i], NULL);

    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
            pthread_join(r[i], NULL);
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear: Could you post `writer` and `read` code?

Comment: Is it on purpose that you pass `i` variable to your thread? It may not be usable in your threads since it will be modified by the main thread.

Comment: @Mathieu Looks like it is posted by the same OP with adifferent name in an earlier question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341997/i-want-to-readers-writers-problem-with-binary-semaphore To the OP: creating multiple accounts is strongly discouraged on SO.

Comment: @su11 You need to post the code for the two functions

Comment: @EugeneSh. The linked question was about another issue (i.e. a core dump). After that has been solved OP have a new problem so it's okay to post a new question. That said I'm not sure why it is a new account

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from the parameter you pass to your thread: It will change to fast for your thread to use it.

One solution could be to create one parameter per thread:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    int *par = malloc(sizeof *par);
    *par = i;
    pthread_create(&w[i], NULL, writer, par);
}
```

**Warning** since some memory has been allocated, it must be deallocated some where:

```
void * writer(void *parameter)
{
    int *par = (int*)parameter;

    /* do some operation with *par */
    printf("I'm thread %d\n", *par );

    /* free it*/
    free(par);    

    .... rest of function code ...
}
```

---

If you're confortable with memory allocation, you could just have some parameters array:

```
/* w array guessed from rest of code*/
thread_t w[5];
int par_w[5];
int i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    par_w[i] = i;        
    pthread_create(&w[i], NULL, writer, &par_w[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably concerns the value of *i* which does not have the right value for the threads, there are two reasons for that

- first you do not have synchronization so the *main* can change the value of *i* before a thread reads it
- second the access from an other thread of a local variable is not guaranty :

> C11 draft standard n1570: 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects 5 An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class specifier static has automatic storage duration, as do some compound literals. The result of attempting to indirectly access an object with automatic storage duration from a thread other than the one with which the object is associated is implementation-defined

So a good way it to allocate memory and give its address, for instance :

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
  int * p = malloc(sizeof(int));

  *p = i;
  pthread_create(&w[i], NULL, writer, p);
}
```

and of course the created thread is responsible to free the memory